# Handle user's denial for sharing information in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I need user's location to proceed my app. At start, I asked user to grant me permission. How to handle if user denied to grant the permission. After Denial I can see user's location in the log. So is there any way to get those geoPoint Or if there is another way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

If the user declines the permission request, their location will not be available to your capsule.

You are able to see the user's location in the log because user location is simulated when working with Bixby Studio's simulator. In a live environment, user location will not be available to your capsule if the user declines the permission request.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/deploying.prep-capsule

Check if the permission is granted using EL or Javascript and remind the user about certain features that might not be functional until permission is granted.